# Use template method of class in child class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I don't use C++ very often, so probably I'll post dummy question.

I have base class

```
class BaseObject {
public:
    template <class T> T* addIntoAutoreleasePool(T*);
};
```

Its implementation:

```
template <class T>
T* BaseObject::addIntoAutoreleasePool(T* argument) {
    return argument;
}
```

When I use this method in **BaseClass** with this code:

```
BaseObject::BaseObject() {
    int a = 5;
    this->addIntoAutoreleasePool<int>(&a);
}
```

it works fine, but if I use this code in child class:

```
class MazeGame : public BaseObject {
public:
    Maze* createMaze();
};

Maze* MazeGame::createMaze() {
    int a = 5;
    this->addIntoAutoreleasePool<int>(&a);
}
```

compiller complains:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "int* BaseObject::addIntoAutoreleasePool<int>(int*)", referenced from:
      MazeGame::createMaze() in MazeGame.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My IDE is XCode 8. I Have some ideas why it happens:

- If I use **addIntoAutoreleasePool** method in both base and child classes it works fine.
- So... I have to force methods generation for needed type.(but I don't know how. I hoped that C++ must do it automatically.). And I need this method for "any type" in me future code, custom classes, ints etc.
- Probably it is just some XCode bug. But any way I have to solve this problem somehow. =(

**PS :Anyway, thanks for attention =)**

Comment: You might want to check [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: WOW! Thanks a lot. It've just solved my problem=)